# AWS CDK, creating an alias record for an existing S3 bucket in Route53

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I wonder how I could get an existing S3 bucket and create an alias record point to it using AWS CDK?

So far so good :

```js
const myExistingBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'myExistingBucket', 'myExistingBucketName')

new route53.ARecord(this, 'myAliasRecord', {
  zone: myHostedZone,
  target: route53.AddressRecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53_targets.BucketWebsiteTarget(myExistingBucket))
});
```

And I got : **Argument of type 'IBucket' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bucket'**.

`fromBucketArn()`, `fromBucketAttributes()` and `fromBucketName()` functions all return `IBucket` type, but the `BucketWebsiteTarget()` function need a `Bucket` type.

So, how am I suppose to get a `Bucket` type from an existing one using AWS CDK?

Comment: I also tried `myExistingBucket as Bucket` without success. The AWS::Route53::RecordSet stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state.

Comment: Are you following the guidelines in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html ?
More specifically:
**Important The bucket must have the same name as your domain or subdomain. For example, if you want to use the subdomain acme.example.com, the name of the bucket must be acme.example.com.**

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice that, but I ended up using CloudFront on top of it to provide HTTPS (which does not have this limitation). You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I ended up using CloudFront to provide HTTPS over S3 Bucket (which is a better practice) based on [AWS CDK Static Site Example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/static-site). `s3BucketSource` accept directly a `IBucket` type.

```js
const myExistingBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'myExistingBucket', 'myExistingBucketName')

// CloudFront distribution that provides HTTPS
const devDistribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'mySiteDistribution', {
  aliasConfiguration: {
    acmCertRef: certArn, // Must be in us-east-1 region.
    names: ['app.example.com'],
    sslMethod: cloudfront.SSLMethod.SNI,
    securityPolicy: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_1_2016,
  },
  originConfigs: [
    {
      s3OriginSource: {
        s3BucketSource: myExistingBucket
      },
      behaviors: [{ isDefaultBehavior: true }],
    }
  ]
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'myAliasRecord', {
  zone: zone,
  target: route53.AddressRecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53_targets.CloudFrontTarget(devDistribution)),
});
```